# What does this sentence *the conditional random variable $x|y$ exists under $\pi$* mean?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

I'm reading [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1302.6989) and don't understand this sentence (in Theorem 3.1 page 28):

> Assume that the conditional random variable $x|y$ **exists under $\pi$** with
> probability distribution denoted $\pi^y(dx)$.

What does the phrase "exists under $\pi$" mean exactly?

Thank you in advance for your explanation!

Comment: Not standard. In fact conditional random variable is a meaningless term.

Comment: Indeed, rigorously, only conditional *distributions* of *random variables* are defined, conditional on some *event, random variable, or sigma algebra*. It is tempting to abuse this terminology and to then talk about “conditional RVs” but I think this causes more confusion than the convenience it provides. To say the “conditional RV” exists then would mean, conditional on $Y=y$, the RV $X$ has conditional distribution with, say, conditional density $f(x|y)=\pi^y(x)$.

Comment: @NapD.Lover, Yes, thank you so much for your help! How about the phrase "exists under $\pi$"? what is the author trying to say?